# Get clickable link in result set Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Query where i need to construct a clickable link in the result grid.

But I can't find a reference anywhere how to be able to escape the html encoding which seems to go on during output.

Example

```
Column ID | View more
1         | http://www.. (should be clickable in the web ui)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your expectation here, but you cannot use the SQL query language in a way to instruct how to format your response into [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) or clickable URL.

In case you are wondering how could be made possible that would require a browser extension, and that should handle this UI thing. Anyway there is no such thing yet. But you are welcome to start one.

There are some Chrome extensions for BigQuery, my favorite is the Streak Development Tools one. You can check out these https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/bigquery

Comment: And if you find that you *can* create a link in the results without using a browser extension, please file a bug against the BigQuery team, since that probably means we're allowing XSS via query results.